# Run different job with different merge request in GitHub Actions using Firebase WebHosting

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, hosting, continuous-deployment, firebase-hosting

I am pretty new to CI/CD, and I am using Firebase WebHosting to host my React app with GitHub Actions. I am able to create two workflows, one for every pull request and the other for merging into development.

But the thing that I want to achieve is when I merge into my staging branch then it should be live on my staging server and when I merge into master it should be live on my production server.

Right now I am able to do only one, either I can deploy it to staging or to production. I have two seperate projects on Firebase as well (project-stg and project-prod) where I wish to deploy staging on project-stg and production on project-prod.

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT_PROD }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: project-prod
```

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT_STG }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: project-stg
```

How can I have these two workflow in a single file, as I suppose I cannot have two firebase-hosting-merge.yml files in my .github/workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename doesn't matter. It's just the default name that Firebase creates files as. You can have two workflows that are `firebase-hosting-merge-staging.yml` and `firebase-hosting-merge-production.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, Abraham for your help. Can you also please help me with the firebaserc and firebase.json. So I have two projects on Firebase as I have mentioned in my question, so how can I configure these files accordingly? In the docs I could see the configuration for multiple hosting on the same project, but I couldn't find anything for multiple projects.